# Error when trying to read a Delta Table [Py4JJavaError]

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse, delta-lake

I have created my very first Delta table using a Notebook in Azure Synapse. I am now trying to read it but I am getting an error. Here is the code I have written (I have masked some of the information) :

```
df = spark.read.format("delta").load('https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/footballdata/delta/football_data/part-00000-c9b34d19-feb5-4774-8e05-0f5d6ee89e47-c000.snappy.parquet')
```

I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_7339/2373797746.py in <module>
----> 1 df = spark.read.format("delta").load('https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/footballdata/delta/football_data/part-00000-c9b34d19-feb5-4774-8e05-0f5d6ee89e47-c000.snappy.parquet')
```

Just a note, the delta_log file is located in the football_data folder.

Comment: You don't need to include the path to the specific parquet file you're reading in `spark.read.format('delta').load()`. Just `https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/footballdata/delta/football_data` as the path for the delta table is enough.

Comment: Please put it down as an answer so I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the path to the specific parquet file you're reading in `spark.read.format('delta').load()`.
Just `https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/footballdata/delta/football_data` as the path for the delta table is enough.